# Where is the plain wire in NI Multisim

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, multisim

Could somebody please tell me where to find wire in the NI Multisim to connect logical gates to the VCC? I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

Double clicking anywhere creates a wire in multisim. You should also be able to click any endpoint to create a wire.

Answer (score 1):

NI Multisim does not offer a separate wire tool. It is available as contextual tool and appears automatically. To wire two components click at source component terminal (say, an IC pin). This will create(start) a wire from there. Now move the mouse pointer and click on the target component terminal to establish a wire connection between the two components.

Also double clicking anywhere on the circuit workspace creates(starts) a wire and you can terminate it by double clicking again at the target location.